# How to add animation to background-image property in body tag?

Tags: css

I'm using the background image in style tag.

```
<style>
body {
 background-image: url("img.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 transition: background-image 4s linear;
 }
</style>
```

I want the image to fade in, without having to add separate divs on the page. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want a CSS only solution (no JavaScript)?

Comment: Yes, without any JS.

Comment: I put up a possible CSS-only solution though with a caveat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using CSS only. However, there is a caveat, CSS cannot wait for an event so it can't know when the whole site is loaded.

Instead in this snippet it waits for 1 second before starting to bring in the background image which is on the before pseudo element of the body.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /*just for demo */
  position: relative;
}

body::before {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
  background-size: cover;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 5s 1 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
Hello, this is some text in the body. It will be seen even before the background starts to fade in.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. This is how you can do that.

```css
@keyframes mymove {
     from {
      /* background: white; */     
     }
     to {
      background: url("https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/welded-metal-chain-various-rigging-260nw-2238426561.jpg");
       }
}
body {        
        animation: mymove 2s infinite;
      }
```

```html
<body><body>
```

Comment: I added another image in the from block, this transition works well. However on first load, the page starts from white. I thought the from section should take care of it, but it isn't.

Comment: Hello @Nikhat. 
It should work fine with your scenario.  May you create another question and include the code? . I try to answer it and I will upvote your question as well. Thank you & have a good day.

Comment: Unfortunately background-image does not animate smoothly on all browsers - on mine the image is just coming in from the white immediately with no fading. The action on trying to animate a background image is not consistent across browsers I believe so this method cannot be used (even with a starting white image).

Comment: @AHaworth. Yes, you are right (immediately with no fading). but your belives is wrong (this method cannot be used). if you want it to fadIn. you need to animate the opacity of the image. I am answering that we can use animation with body tag.

Comment: @ABDULAZIZNOREDINQADMOR on some browsers you will find that they will fade between one image and the next in an animation, but unfortunately not all. However, you cannot use the fading in on the background of the body itself as that would mean anything else in the body like text also starts off invisible which is not what is required.

Comment: @AHaworth. For older browsers, there is some addition CSS needs to be added like so: @-webkit-keyframes{}

Answer (score 1):

## How to fadein the background

There are several ways to achieve that but the easiest is proably using the `transition` css property.

### CSS transition property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

> Transitions enable you to define the transition between two states of
> an element. Different states may be defined using pseudo-classes like
> :hover or :active or dynamically set using JavaScript.

Usually transitions are applied with events at the css layer. So for example you may have a third rule that ***on :hover*** will apply the transition of a given css property (`opacity` in this case). But here we need to do it on document laod and there's no css selector for that so we'll add the class with a slow delay after the document is ready.

### Demo:

So in this demo here I have a css rule addressing the `.bg` elements setting their background in a pseudo element covering the whole parent element but with `opacity: 0`.

The reason why I used the pseudoelement `::before` it's because the transition will be limited to the background itself and not the whole body content. ***Important:*** I set the `z-index: -1` so that the element will be granted to stay on background.

Then there's another rule addressing `.show` elements that will set the `opacity: 1` with a transition lasting 5 seconds.

The `bg` class is given to the `body` in the html and the class `show` gets applied via js on the event `DOMContentLoaded` (when the page is ready).

The same effect can be achieve clicking on a button in the page that will call that same `fadeInBackground` function. That function will remove the `show` class and will wait an instant before adding the class back.

Such delay is important because the css engine will react badly otherwise if you remove and add the class too quickly it won't perform the animation (that's for the reason explained above on css events compared to triggering the action via js).

```js
//on page load, fades the background in
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> fadeInBackground());

function fadeInBackground(){
  //removes the class show from body
  document.body.classList.remove('show');
  //waits 200ms before adding the class show to body
  setTimeout(()=> document.body.classList.add('show'), 200);  
}
```

```css
.bg::before {
  content: ' ';
  
  display: block;  
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  
  background-image: url('https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/cors-caron-bog-pools-as-seen-boardwalk-national-nature-reserve-near-tregaron-wales-60217166.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
  
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.show::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

div{  
  background: white;
  opacity: .8;
  padding: 1em;
  background: dashed 4px gray;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg">    
  
  <div>
    <p>This is the page content slightly faded relative to the background</p>
    <br>
    <p>The fadein is expected to happen at page load but you can trigger the action also from here</p>
    <button onclick="fadeInBackground()">Fade in background</button>
  </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: There's a lot in here - and if a JS solution were acceptable this would work fine. However, there is some spurious stuff (are we looking at ChatGPT here? Doesn't invalidate the answer, just makes it more difficult to get to the actual solution for this particular scenario.)

Comment: @AHaworth chatGPT is my best friend of course :D but the answer is all on my own. Its long content shows.. well chatGPT also is very verbose actually but I think you can clearly see this is not the case. The reason why I used javascript it's for the reasons I explained since the beginning in the answer. I'm using css for the animation but I'm setting the class at page load (via js) and there's no css event for that. I also explained that's the reason for the delay. I spent a while to get there.. and I'd be curious to hear a css only solution if any. And there is indeed as shown on other answer

Comment: I used transition instead of animation because I thought it was useless to transition from 0 to 1 with no granularity and no special time function

Comment: I withdraw the ChatGPT remark! Transition is of course fine if using the JS route, but I don't understand the granularity and time function bit as you could do that with an animation property also - or am I missing something?

Comment: @AHaworth by that I meant I didn't feel like it was worthwhile defining the animation keyframes and wanted to strip it down to the minimum. But an attempt was worth the effort and the other working solution shows. In my head I'm supposed to resort to animation when I need very fine control on how the value of the property is going to change over time. But here it's another game.. the animation property doesn't require an event that changes the class of the element like transition does, thus it doesn't require the js approach. I'm forced to upvote it :D

Comment: Very generous of you considering my ChatGPT remark! Actually in practice I too would use JS for this as it really does require to wait for loading to be absolutely sure (perhaps with a timeout as well, in case loading never ends). But the OP didn't want JS.

Comment: @AHaworth I learnt something today and things are now better sculpted in my head. Writing answers makes a lot in terms of learning and thank you for the fruitful conversation of course